# Zoom out in selenium and performing the further UI actions results in element not found exception - sleep time also not working: How to overcome?

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Issue: element is not visible in browser(100% zoom) to click in selenium automation and so I added zoom out and element got visible now in the browser- but after zoom out, no action is performed (elements were not reachable) and got stucked with error - org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:.

Could anyone provide any idea/steps? for below queries?

1. If element is not visible due to browser size, how to make the code to click the element? -
   error - org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable
   to locate element:

2.Element is not visible in browser(100% zoom) to click in selenium automation and so I added zoom out and element got visible now in the browser but after zoom out, no action is performed and got stucked with error - org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:

code rough:

```
WebDriver driver32=new ChromeDriver();
            
 driver32.manage().window().maximize();
                

driver32.get("chrome://settings/");
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)bugmetrics;
executor.executeScript("chrome.settingsPrivate.setDefaultZoom(0.9);");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
          
                driver32.get("URL");
       
              
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
driver32.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"s2id_filter-dropdown\"]/a")).click();
               
driver32.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"select2-drop\"]/ul/li[11]/div/span")).click();
```

Comment: `NoSuchElementException` has nothing to do with element visibility. Even if element is not visible (but present) it has to be successfuly located.

Comment: @pburgr - While visible it was working properly , but in one url 'add' button is not showing and it was causing error. now error was - org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (438, 630)
Do you have any suggestion here?

Comment: Check the full text of the exception. If the is 'other element would recieve the click...' there will be some idetification of the overlaying element.

Comment: Its not shown, still I used javascript executor command and able to click it. But the problem is input values entered before is not considering and it remains blank :(

Comment: driver32.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[2]/span/input")).sendKeys(cumtodate);
                
          
                    
          
                WebElement element = driver32.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/button[2]"));

                JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)bugmetrics;
                
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", element);

Comment: Depending how the input field is coded click may be required before entering value.

Comment: Tried click and clear but still not working. Value got entered properly but as I calling java executor method in next line, it was not taking input. what to do?  (As xpath is clear and good here)

Comment: Can u provide url or page source code?

Comment: URL won't work for you, As a small help, can i get ur number to discuss on this?

Comment: @pburgr - If the is 'other element would recieve the click...' there will be some idetification of the overlaying element.  - now this was happening, what to do here?

Comment: Basicaly if you can not click specific element manualy even selenium won't succeed. Check your scenario.

Comment: Yeah yes, due to more data particular UI element is not showing in window size and  it can't able to click it. What could be the solution here to overcome?